# Forcing a Vaadin Tabsheet to use the CloseHandler

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin Tabsheet. All tabs are closable. I have defined a custom CloseHandler. When a Tab is closed via the small x button, the the CloseHadler executes; however, if I close the tab programmatically

```
 TabSheet parent = (TabSheet) this.getParent();
 parent.removeTab(parent.getTab(this));
```

The close handler does not execute. Is there a way to force the CloseHandler to execute before the Tab is removed.

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: If you look at the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.java) you'll notice that the `TabSheet`'s constructor defines a default `CloseListener` that simply calls `tabsheet.removeComponent(c)` which is what `removeTab(Tab tab)` does. Guess what would happen if one called the other :-). Under the circumstances I'd conclude that besides actually invoking the `CloseHandler` yourself, there's no other (clean and simple) way of programatically triggering its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `tabsheet.removeComponent(c)` gives the same behavior. I was hoping to be able to invoke the CloseHandler by sending a CloseEvent like [fireSelectedTabChange](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#fireSelectedTabChange%28%29) but I don't see anything in the documentation that would allow me to do this. Guess I will have to come up with dirty solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to extend the `TabSheet` class and override  `removeTab()` to force it to execute the `closeHandler`. As the `TabSheet.closeHandler` is private you'll need to override this field and its setter too. Vaadin could make things simpler (changing the `closeHandler` to `protected` or providing a getter) but I don't see it as a "dirty" solution.

```
public class MyTabSheet extends TabSheet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private CloseHandler closeHandler;

    @Override
    public void removeTab(Tab tab) {

        if (closeHandler != null) {
            closeHandler.onTabClose(this, tab.getComponent());
        }

        super.removeTab(tab);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCloseHandler(CloseHandler handler) {
        closeHandler = handler;
        // needed for TabSheet.TabsheetServerRpcImpl
        super.setCloseHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

If you want you could create a feature request at Vaadin ([vaadin.com/bug](http://vaadin.com/bug)), maybe the `closeHandler` should be called by default. There's already the [#10555](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/10555) but it's 3 years old...